# MQTT file persistence in apache nms C#

Tags: c#, apache, mqtt, nms

I have been using eclipse paho mqtt library and there is an option for file persistence there. I couldn't find any resource on mqtt file persistence on apache nms as I am trying to do the same in c#. Anyone has used this before?

Comment: What NMS library are you asking about, add more details so people can answer